# JMS subscriber stops getting messages from topic after a while

Tags: java, jms, subscription, jms-topic

I noticed that my processes that subscribe to a JMS topic stop getting messages posted to that topic after some time in which no messages were posted to the topic (I can't quantify precisely this time, but let's say a minute).
I am using JBoss Application Server v4.2 to manage the topics.

Any idea why is that and how to ensure that my subscribers would still be able to get messages even after days that nothing was posted to their topics?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/36233 describes similar problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a file called 'remoting-bisocket-service.xml' in [install directory]/jboss/server/default/deploy/jboss-messaging.sar

In it the default timeout is usually set to 30 seconds. This value needs to be set to 0 for an infinite timeout.

Comment: Take into account that infinite timeout could cause https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBREM-1308 due to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBMESSAGING-1805